# SetCurrentPosition for ConvertView Android

Tags: android

I want my CoverFlow to setCurrentPosition() to any number i want. But i can't find any built in function to do this task in my CoverFlow. Does someone has a solution for this please help.

```
 CoverFlow coverFlow = (CoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflowid);
             coverFlow.setAnimationDuration(1000);
             coverFlow.setSpacing(pixels);
    coverflowAdapter=new CoverflowAdapter(CarouselCompte.this, PostList);
    coverFlow.setAdapter(coverflowAdapter);
```

Comment: coverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply set position to Listview where your adapter is setting up ,

```
listview.setSelection(position)
```

The adapter will set that specific position .